# Comparing two algorithms for all-pairs shortest paths

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, data-structures, asymptotics

I read in my notes:

> If we use Dijkstra $|V|$ times ($|V|$ number of vertices) for finding **all-pairs shortest paths** in graph $G$, we get time complexity for Dijkstra algorithm as $O(VE+ V^2 \log V)$, and if we run Bellman–Ford algorithm $|V|$ times, we get time $O(V^2E)$.

The above details are not important.

I read too, that Dijkstra's algorithm works better for sparse graph, that is, $O(VE+ V^2 \log V)$ is better than $O(V^2E)$ asymptotically for sparse graphs.

I think sparse graphs are graphs satisfying $ |E| = O(V)$  or $E=o(V^2/\log V)$. In fact, I have two misunderstandings:

1. Which one is more common as the definition of a sparse graph?
2. According to 1, how we can intuitively understand that $O(VE+ V^2 \log V)$ is better asymptotically than $O(V^2E)$? At least I think the reverse is true.

Comment: What is the specific doubt you have? If it clear to you how the given time complexity have been obtained (for $E= \Theta(V^2)$ !!) then it should be clear why Dijkstra should be preferred.
Notice, however, that these are definitely NOT the best known algorithms to solve APSP in dense graphs.

Comment: $V^2 \log V = O(VE)$ as soon as $E = \Omega(V \log V)$. Since we are dealing with dense graphs, this additive term can be safely omitted by Dijkstra's algorithm complexity.  Then you are just comparing $\Theta(VE)$ with $\Theta(V^2 E)$. It is immediate that the first complexity is better.

Comment: Dense graph is not a formally defined concept. It means a graph with "many edges" compared to the number of vertices. Clearly a graph with $\Theta(V^2)$ edges is dense, but the converse might or might not be true depending on the context.

Comment: $VE$ is obviously better than $V^2 E$, and $V^2 \log V$ is better than $V^2 E$ when $E = \omega(\log V)$, which holds for any reasonable graph.

Comment: @Sara, sorry I misunderstood your question. Anyway, Dmitry's comment settles it.

Comment: There is no standard definition for *sparse graph*. Some common definitions are: $o(n^2)$ edges, $O(n^{1-\epsilon})$ edges, $O(n\log^C n)$ edges, $O(n)$ edges.

Comment: Dmitry answered this above. For connected graphs, $E \ge V-1$, and given this, you can easily compare the running times.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133376/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3950318/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard definition for sparse graphs. Some common definition include graphs in which $E = o(V^2)$, $E=O(V^{2-\epsilon})$, $E = O(V^{1+\epsilon})$, $E=O(V^{1+o(1)})$, $E = O(V\log^C V)$, and $E = O(V)$.

In most situations, it is safe to assume that the graph is connected, and so $E \geq V-1$. In such cases, $VE + V^2\log V = O(V^2 E)$, and so an upper bound on the running time of the form $O(VE + V^2\log V)$ is better than an upper bound of the form $O(V^2 E)$: indeed, the former implies the latter.

Comment: The important inequality is $E \geq V-1$.

Comment: No, because to compare the running times we need a *lower bound* on $E$, not an *upper bound*.

Comment: Yes, that's right.